# Getting a 405 HTTP error when POSTing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, http, http-post

In xcode, I use `doHTTPPOST` method to write a data to a XML file residing in the server (IIS 6.0).

I get http 405 method not found error, `enable GET,POST, PUT method in the server.`

Do I need to do something in order to write contents to a file from xcode?

I can use `doHTTPGET` to read the contents of the same file? Any thoughts?

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: I think he wants to HTTP post to an IIS site from xcode (i think this should be clarified, can you change the tags on a question? Needs to specify iphone or whatever he's using (i never posted a question, only answered)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into ASIHTTP, there is great documentation on how to upload files.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

To build xml files to a file or to a variable, the best framework i have found is:

XSWI library - https://github.com/skjolber/xswi

Comment: Thanks, do i need to change any IIS settings to write inside a file?

Comment: No IIS Changes, i think NTFS permission need to be applied to the directory you are storing the file (you need to give the "Internet Guest Account" full control (or at least write of that path)     Also, when you say "write inside a file" you usually are posting a new one from the iOS device and replacing what's there (depending on the file name of course).. You need to make the actual webpage accept the HTTP post (there's numerous examples of this in php or asp.net etc)